# Issue with getting 'Click' Event Listeners to execute

Tags: javascript, local-storage, addeventlistener

So I have three unique buttons that are coded with their own unique event listener processes.  However, none of them execute when I click on them.

index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Ghost Bear Pizza is a fictional pizza restaurant chain with the mission of service only the most exotic ingredients and toppings for their pizza.">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/ionicons.min.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="queries.css">
    <title>Welcome to Ghost Bear Pizza</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="nav__logo">
                <img src="icons/pizza-logo.svg" alt="Company Logo" class="logo" />
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                    <!-- <div>Icons made by <a href="" title="xnimrodx">xnimrodx</a> from <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon">www.flaticon.com</a></div> -->

                    <div class="nav__bar">
                        <ul class="nav__bar__ul">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">About Us</a>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Menu</a>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Locations</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="cart">
                                    <a href="cart.html">
                                        <ion-icon name="cart-outline"></ion-icon>:<span>0</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="header__company-name">
            <div class="header__company-name__content">
            <h1>Ghost Bear Pizza</h1>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-order">Order Now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="about">
        <h2><span class="section-dash">&mdash;</span> About Us <span class="section-dash">&mdash;</span></h2>
        <p>
            For years, the Ghost Bear Pizza Founders would get together at their local tabletop gaming store on every Thursday night of the week to play their session of Battletech.  Each week, they would order a cheese pizza from the local restaurant.  However, the Founders were never satisfied with the toppings that the restaurant offered, so they would always cook their own ingredients and add it to the ordered pizza.
            <br />
            <br />
            So one night, one of the Founders came up with an idea to have the three of them open up their own pizza restaurant.  There, they would use nothing but the most rare and exotic pizza ingredients and toppings that could be offered.  Extra spicy pepperoni, chorizo, savory pineapple (that's right....SAVORY pineapple).  You name it, they had it.  And that was how the first ever Ghost Bear Pizza was born in Noblesville, IN.
            <br />
            <br />
            For the next thirty years, Ghost Bear Pizza built three more restaurants throughout the northern-Indianapolis area.  Along the way, they came up with the idea of building a small section within each of their restaurants where customers could bring in their own ingredients, cook them right there in the store (under proper supervision), and use those ingredients for their own pizza meals that they would order at that restaurant.
            <br />
            <br />
            <span class="about_large">Ghost Bear Pizza locations are independently, locally-owned and operated.</span>
            <br />
            <span class="about_small">All prices are subject to change at any time.  Ghost Bear Pizza is not a registered trademark.  Seriously.  I made it up just for this website!</span>
        </p>
    </section>

    <section class="menu">
        <h2>
            <span class="section-dash">&mdash;</span> Menu <span class="section-dash">&mdash;</span>
        </h2>

        <ul class="menu-food clearfix">
            <h3>Pizzas:</h3>
            <li>
                <figure class="menu-photo">
                    <img src="img/pepperoni-min.jpg" alt="Spicy Pepperoni Pizza" />
                    <div class="menu-name"><strong>Spicy Pepperoni</strong></div>
                </figure>
            </li>
            <li>
                <figure class="menu-photo">
                    <img src="img/chorizo-min.jpg" alt="Chorizo Pizza" />
                    <div class="menu-name"><strong>Zesty Chorizo</strong></div>
                </figure>
            </li>
            <li>
                <figure class="menu-photo">
                    <img src="img/pineapple-min.jpg" alt="Savory Pineapple Pizza" />
                    <div class="menu-name"><strong>Savory Pineapple</strong></div>
                </figure>
            </li>
            <li>
                <figure class="menu-photo">
                    <img src="img/alphastrike-min.jpg" alt="The Alpha Strike" />
                    <div class="menu-name"><strong>"The Alpha Strike"</strong></div>
                </figure>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="menu-food clearfix">
            <h3>Appetizers:</h3>
            <li>
                <figure class="menu-photo">
                    <img src="img/breadsticks-min.jpg" alt="Breadsticks" />
                    <div class="menu-name"><strong>Breadsticks</strong></div>
                </figure>
            </li>
            <li>
                <figure class="menu-photo">
                    <img src="img/stuffedbreadsticks-min.jpg" alt="Stuffed Breadsticks" />
                    <div class="menu-name"><strong>Stuffed Breadsticks</strong></div>
                </figure>
            </li>
            <li>
                <figure class="menu-photo">
                    <img src="img/cheesebread-min.jpeg" alt="Garlic Cheese Bread" />
                    <div class="menu-name"><strong>Garlic Cheese Bread</strong></div>
                </figure>
            </li>
            <li>
                <figure class="menu-photo">
                    <img src="img/poppers-min.jpg" alt="Chorizo-stuffed Jalapeno Poppers" />
                    <div class="menu-name"><strong>Chorizo-stuffed Jalapeno Poppers</strong></div>
                </figure>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>

    <section class="locations">
        <h2>
            <span class="section-dash">&mdash;</span> Locations <span class="section-dash">&mdash;</span>
        </h2>
        <div class="location__img-container">
            <figure class="location__image">
                <img src="img/noblesvillemini.jpg" alt="Noblesville" />
                <h4>12345 Kerensky Way<br />Noblesville, IN 46060</h4>
            </figure>
            <figure class="location__image">
                <img src="img/broadripplemini.jpg" alt="Broad Ripple" />
                <h4>24680 Jorgensson Blvd.<br />Broad Ripple, IN 46220</h4>
            </figure>
            <figure class="location__image">
                <img src="img/carmelmini.jpg" alt="Carmel" />
                <h4>13579 Tseng Court<br />Carmel, IN 46069</h4>
            </figure>
            <figure class="location__image">
                <img src="img/kokomomini.jpg" alt="Kokomo" />
                <h4>54321 Tukayyid St.<br />Kokomo, IN 46901</h4>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="order">
        <h2>
            <span class="section-dash">&mdash;</span> Place an order <span class="section-dash">&mdash;</span>
        </h2>

            <br />
            <h3 class="food-header">Pizzas:</h3>
                <div class="pizza-container">
                    <div class="order-pizza">
                        <div class="order-pizza-item">
                            <figure class="order-photo">
                                <img src="img/pepperoni-min.jpg" alt="Spicy Pepperoni Pizza" />
                                <div class="order-name">Spicy Pepperoni</div>
                                <button class="btn-form-order">Add to Cart</button>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="order-pizza-item">
                            <figure class="order-photo">
                                <img src="img/chorizo-min.jpg" alt="Chorizo Pizza" />
                                <div class="order-name">Zesty Chorizo</div>
                                <button class="btn-form-order">Add to Cart</button>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="order-pizza-item">
                            <figure class="order-photo">
                                <img src="img/pineapple-min.jpg" alt="Savory Pineapple Pizza" />
                                <div class="order-name">Savory Pineapple</div>
                                <button class="btn-form-order">Add to Cart</button>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="order-pizza-item">
                            <figure class="order-photo">
                                <img src="img/alphastrike-min.jpg" alt="The Alpha Strike" />
                                <div class="order-name">"The Alpha Strike"</div>
                                <button class="btn-form-order">Add to Cart</button>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <h3 class="food-header">Appetizers:</h3>

                <div class="appetizer-container">
                    <div class="order-appetizer">
                        <div class="order-appetizer-item">
                            <figure class="order-photo">
                                <img src="img/breadsticks-min.jpg" alt="Breadsticks" />
                                <div class="order-name">Breadsticks</div>
                                <button class="btn-form-order">Add to Cart</button>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="order-appetizer-item">
                            <figure class="order-photo">
                                <img src="img/stuffedbreadsticks-min.jpg" alt="Stuffed Breadsticks" />
                                <div class="order-name">Stuffed Breadsticks</div>
                                <button class="btn-form-order">Add to Cart</button>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="order-appetizer-item">
                            <figure class="order-photo">
                                <img src="img/cheesebread-min.jpeg" alt="Garlic Cheese Bread" />
                                <div class="order-name">Garlic Cheese Bread</div>
                                <button class="btn-form-order">Add to Cart</button>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="order-appetizer-item">
                            <figure class="order-photo">
                                <img src="img/poppers-min.jpg" alt="Chorizo-stuffed Jalapeno Poppers" />
                                <div class="order-name">Chorizo-stuffed Jalapeno Poppers</div>
                                <button class="btn-form-order">Add to Cart</button>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="checkout">
                    <button class="btn-checkout">Checkout</button>
                </div>
    </section>

    <footer>
        <p>&copy; Chris Rumler<span class="copyright"></span></p>
        <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon>
        <p>Please visit my LinkedIn profile: <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/chrisrumler/">linkedin.com/in/chrisrumler/</a></p>
    </footer>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.4.0/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

cart.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'>
    <title>Ghost Bear Pizza Shopping Cart</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class='cart-header'>
        <div class='overlay'>
            <nav class='cart-nav'>
                <h2>Your current order</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='index.html'>Back to Home</a></li>
                    <li class='cart'>
                        <a href='cart.html' class='cart-link'>
                            <ion-icon name='cart-outline'></ion-icon>:<span>0</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class='products-container'>
        <div class='product-header'>
            <h5 class='product-title'>FOOD ITEM</h5>
            <h5 class='product-price'>PRICE</h5>
            <h5 class='product-quantity'>QUANTITY</h5>
            <h5 class='product-total'>TOTAL</h5>
        </div>
        <div class='products'>

        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <p>&copy; My Name<span class="copyright"></span></p>
        <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon>
        <p>Please visit my LinkedIn profile: <a href="https://www.linkedin.com">linkedin.com</a></p>
    </footer>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.4.0/dist/ionicons.js'></script>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Script.js file:

```
'use strict';

//! Updates Copyright year within Footer section
let copyrightYear = new Date().getFullYear();
document.querySelector('.copyright').innerHTML = ' | ' + copyrightYear;

//! Grabs the "Add to Cart" button
let carts = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-form-order');

//! Stores catalog of pizza products for sale
let products = [
    {
        name: 'Spicy Pepperoni Pizza',
        tag: 'pepperoni-min',
        price: 20,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        name: 'Zesty Chorizo Pizza',
        tag: 'chorizo-min',
        price: 20,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        name: 'Savory Pineapple Pizza',
        tag: 'pineapple-min',
        price: 20,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        name: 'The Alpha Strike',
        tag: 'alphastrike-min',
        price: 30,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        name: 'Breadsticks',
        tag: 'breadsticks-min',
        price: 5,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        name: 'Stuffed Breadsticks',
        tag: 'stuffedbreadsticks-min',
        price: 8,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        name: 'Garlic Cheese Bread',
        tag: 'cheesebread-min',
        price: 7,
        inCart: 0
    },
    {
        name: 'Chorizo Stuffed Jalapeno Poppers',
        tag: 'poppers-min',
        price: 10,
        inCart: 0
    }
];

for (let i = 0; i < carts.length; i++) {
    carts[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        cartNumbers(products[i]);
        totalCost(products[i]);
    })
};

//! Function that checks the number of products currently in cart and updates the Cart button's number value on page load
function onLoadCartNumbers() {
    let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');

    if (productNumbers) {
        document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = productNumbers;
    }
};

//! Local Storage function for cart
function cartNumbers(product, action) {
    let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');

    productNumbers = parseInt(productNumbers);

    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');

    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);

    if (action == 'decrease') {
        localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', productNumbers - 1);
        document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = productNumbers - 1;
    } else if (productNumbers) {
        localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', productNumbers + 1);
        document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = productNumbers + 1;
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', 1);
        document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = 1
    }
    setItems(product);
};

function setItems(product) {
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
    console.log('My cartItems are', cartItems);

    //! If statement starts adding to inCart value for each product item
    if (cartItems !== null) {

        //! This checks to see if a second (or more) product is clicked on and, if so, adds it to the 'product' object

        if (cartItems[product.tag] == undefined) {
            cartItems = {
                ...cartItems,
                [product.tag]: product
            }
        }
        cartItems[product.tag].inCart += 1;
    } else {
        product.inCart = 1;

        cartItems = {
            [product.tag]: product
        }
    }
    localStorage.setItem('productsInCart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
};

//! Function that calculates total cost of product(s) added to cart
function totalCost(product, action) {
    let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');

    if (action == 'decrease') {
        cartCost = parseInt(cartCost);

        localStorage.setItem('totalCost', cartCost - product.price);
    } else if (cartCost != null) {
        cartCost = parseInt(cartCost);
        localStorage.setItem('totalCost', cartCost + product.price);
    } else if (!product.price){
        cartCost = parseInt(cartCost);
        cartCost = 0;
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('totalCost', product.price);
    }
};

function displayCart() {
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    let productContainer = document.querySelector('.products');
    let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');

    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);

    if (cartItems && productContainer) {
        productContainer.innerHTML = '';
        Object.values(cartItems).map(item => {
            productContainer.innerHTML += `
            <div class='product'>
                <ion-icon name='close-circle'></ion-icon>
                <img src='./img/${item.tag}.jpg' />
                <span class='cart-item-label'>${item.name}</span>
            </div>
            <div class='product-price'>$${item.price}.00</div>
            <div class='product-quantity'>
                <ion-icon class='decrease' name='remove-circle'></ion-icon>
                <span>${item.inCart}</span>

                <ion-icon class='increase' name='add-circle'></ion-icon>
            </div>
            <div class='product-total'>
                $${item.inCart * item.price}.00
            </div>
            `;
        });

        productContainer.innerHTML += `
            <div class='basketTotalContainer'>
                <h4 class='basketTotalTitle'>Basket Total</h4>
                <h4 class='basketTotal'>$${cartCost}.00</h4>
            </div>
        `
        deleteButtons();
        manageQuantity();
    }
};

function deleteButtons() {
    let deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.product ion-icon');
    let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');
    let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
    let productName;

    for(let i = 0; i < deleteButtons.length; i++) {
        deleteButtons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
            productName = deleteButtons[i].parentElement.textContent.toLocaleLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'').trim();
           
            localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', productNumbers - cartItems[productName].inCart);
            localStorage.setItem('totalCost', cartCost - (cartItems[productName].price * cartItems[productName].inCart));

            delete cartItems[productName];
            localStorage.setItem('productsInCart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));

            displayCart();
            onLoadCartNumbers();
        })
    }
};

function manageQuantity() {
    let decreaseButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.decrease');
    let increaseButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.increase');
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
    let currentQuantity = 0;
    let currentProduct = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < decreaseButtons.length; i++) {
        decreaseButtons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
            currentQuantity = decreaseButtons[i].parentElement.querySelector('span').textContent;
            console.log(currentQuantity);
            currentProduct = decreaseButtons[i].parentElement.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.querySelector('span').textContent.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '');
            console.log(currentProduct);

            if (cartItems[currentProduct].inCart > 1) {
                cartItems[currentProduct].inCart -= 1;
                cartNumbers(cartItems[currentProduct], 'decrease');
                totalCost(cartItems[currentProduct], 'decrease');
                localStorage.setItem('productsInCart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
                displayCart();
            }
        })
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < increaseButtons.length; i++) {
        increaseButtons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
            currentQuantity = increaseButtons[i].parentElement.querySelector('span').textContent;
            console.log(currentQuantity);
            currentProduct = increaseButtons[i].parentElement.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.querySelector('span').textContent.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '').trim();
            console.log(currentProduct);


            cartItems[currentProduct].inCart += 1;
            cartNumbers(cartItems[currentProduct]);
            totalCost(cartItems[currentProduct]);
            localStorage.setItem('productsInCart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
            displayCart();
        })
    };
};

onLoadCartNumbers();
displayCart();
```

styles.css code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300;400;700&display=swap');

/* Ghost Bear blue: #2376bc | rgb(35, 118, 188) */

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #414141;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.cart-header {
    background-image: url('img/cart-header.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rbga(10,10,10.0.3);
}

.cart-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 50px 60px 0 60px;
}

.cart-nav li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.cart-nav li span {padding-left: 5px;}

.cart-link {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.cart ion-icon {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.products-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    max-width: 1000px;
}

.products-container ion-icon {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #2376bc;
    margin: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.product-header {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #2376bc;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.product {
    width: 45%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: right;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2376bc;
}

.product-title {width: 45%;}

.product-price {
    width: 15%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2376bc;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.product-quantity {
    width: 30%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2376bc;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.product-total {
    width: 10%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2376bc;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.cart-item-label {font-size: 90%}

.products {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.products img {width: 75px;}

.basketTotalContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.basketTotalTitle {width: 30%;}

.basketTotal {width: 10%;}
```

Here is a screenshot of my cart with one of each product item added into the cart, in case it may help someone fully visualize how I'm wanting this to work:

[Snapshot of Cart.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buD7x.jpg)

Comment: I tried copying the code into new files to reproduce the issue, but I'm not finding any buttons with the class ".decrease" in the html code provided, did you also mean to include the cart and index code? Also including the estyle woud help

Comment: So the ".decrease" and ".increase" classes do not exist until the displayCart() function starts running.

Comment: I don't believe you need anything from the index.html for the issue that I'm having, but I'll go ahead and add the styles.css code in my original post.

Comment: In your JS you have a line: `let carts = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-form-order');` But I can't seem to locate `btn-form-order` anywhere else in the provided code?

Comment: That's just the class for the button that resides within the index.html that adds the item into the shopping cart.

Comment: Also, I'll add that whenever I click on any of these buttons, my browser console gives me the following error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inCart' of undefined"

Comment: Just in case, I went ahead and added my index.html code in the OP

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I need to change my .trim() methods so that it matches the names of my products in the way that the event handlers need them to be.